# getting 404 error for bower components

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to run my application using gulp task runner and i have installed few bower components and angular is one of them

When i try to run the application I am getting errors :
[image: screenshot]

In index.html:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin/plugins/js/bootstrap-accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-socialshare/dist/angular-socialshare.min.js"></script>
```

I have also included the path but still getting the same errors.

Comment: Is your dev server hosting root? Its likely that its hosting /dist or /src or something and these are not available.

Comment: Its just the yeoman boiler plate which I am using and I choosed to use gulp and then to run the application I am doing gulp serve

Comment: Have you ran Bower install. Do these files exist to be served?

Comment: yes I have done bower install and I could see those files in bower components folder in my application folder

Comment: You must use asnyc module loader  like requirejs because of peer dependency between those js . For eg angular depend on the jquery.

Comment: Please add express app.js where you defined static resource path

Answer (score 1):

- Test `404 error` urls from console by run those into the browser. It will ensure that files were available in the location or not.
- Use relative path in all files if `index.html` and `bower_components` are in same location.

  **Ex :** `./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js`

When your angular code start executing, `angular` does not exist.

> AngularJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

you are trying to access a variable called angular which is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

1. "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined".
2. For this error make sure you have the right version of NodeJS installed with respect to your project.
3. **npm install -g node@7.10.1**.  whatever version you want after the @ symbol.
4. You can check the version by **node    -v**.
5. For Bower Components.
   **bower install** .